# Generate method aspectOf() with gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, aop, aspectj

Can't generate `aspectOf()` method wih gradle plugin.

My AspectJ config class and some aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class SendToAspect {

    @Around("execution (public * *(..)) && @annotation(ann)")
    public Object execute(final ProceedingJoinPoint point, final SendTo ann) throws Throwable {

        return point.proceed();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AspectjConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SendToAspect sendToAspect() {
        return Aspects.aspectOf(SendToAspect.class);
    }
}
```

**My build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id "io.freefair.aspectj.base" version "5.1.0"
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencyManagement {
        dependencies {
            dependency 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    group 'com.example'
    version '0.0.1-snapshot'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    }
}

configure([project(':my-service')]) {

    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.freefair.aspectj.base'

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
        implementation 'org.springframework:spring-aspects'
        implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt'
   }
}
```

**After building and running my springBoot app I get the same error:**

```
error creating bean with name 'sendToAspect' defined in class path resource
[com/example/config/aspectj/AspectjConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.utils.aop.SendToAspect]:
Factory method 'sendToAspect' threw exception; nested exception is org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: 

Exception while initializing com.restaurantclub.soa.utils.aop.SendToAspect: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.restaurantclub.soa.utils.aop.SendToAspect.aspectOf()
```

What needs to be done or which plugin should i use to work?

My Gradle version: **5.2.1**

Comment: Can you show how do you run your app? Do specify javaagent aspectj and spring-instrument?

Comment: @Krzysztof Kaszkowiak just run   SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class) from intellij idea
whitout any jvm args
"Do specify javaagent aspectj and spring-instrument?" - no

Comment: @Krzysztof Kaszkowiak I thought the gradle aspectj  plugin generated aspect-classes in compile time like maven but 
it did not happen

Comment: I wrote this answer, hope it helps someone, and if anyone can improve it, please comment on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74660835/2694806

Answer (score 0):

Solution - just use 'io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving' instead io.freefair.aspectj.base