# Micrometer TimedAspect doesn't intercept calls to methods annotated with @Timed

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, micrometer

I am trying to use [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) to record execution time in my Java application. This is related to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575829/how-to-use-micrometer-timed-annotation-outside-of-spring-in-a-java-application) about used `@Timed` annotation.

I have a class `CountedObject` that has the following 2 methods:

```
@Measured
@Timed(value = "timer1")
public void measuredFunction() {
    try {
        int sleepTime = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime * 1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

@Timed(value = "timer2")
public void timedFunction() {
    try {
        int sleepTime = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime * 1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

I have defined a custom annotation `@Measured`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Measured {
    
}
```

And a `MeasuredAspect` to intercept calls to methods annotated with my `@Measured` annotation:

```
@Aspect
public class MeasuredAspect {
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Measured)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        return AppMetrics.getInstance().handle(pjp);

    }
}
```

In my `AppMetrics` class I initialize an instance of micrometer's [TimedAspect](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/aop/TimedAspect.java) and in the `handle(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)` method pass the `ProceedingJoinPoint pjp` to the TimedAspect instance.

```
public class AppMetrics {
    private static final AppMetrics instance = new AppMetrics();
    
    private MeterRegistry registry;
    private TimedAspect timedAspect;
    
    public static AppMetrics getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    
    private AppMetrics() {
        this.registry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
        this.timedAspect = new TimedAspect(registry);
    }
    
    public Object handle(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        return timedAspect.timedMethod(pjp);
    }
}
```

In my application main, I create an object of `CountedObject` and invoke `measuredFunction()` and `timedFunction()` then I check my `registry.getMeters();` only **timer1**  used by the `measuredFunction()` [which is annotated by both @Measured and @Timed] is found, while the **timer2** that should be used by `timedFunction()` [annotated only by [@Timed](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/annotation/Timed.java)] doesn't exist.

I am using eclipse with [AspectJ Development Tools Plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/) and my project is a Gradle project with AspectJ capability. I am using `id "io.freefair.aspectj" version "5.1.1"` plugin in my Gradle plugins. This is a basic java application not a Spring app.

What configurations needs to be done or what code changes are required so that micrometer [TimedAspect](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/aop/TimedAspect.java) can intercept my method calls directly [i.e `timedFunction()` should be timed and **timer2** should be found in the registry] without the need of my custom annotation?

Answer (score 2):

I created an example project for you:

https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726

Quoting the read-me (sorry, but answers only containing links are frowned upon on StackOverflow):

---

In https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1149 and on StackOverflow, an FAQ about Micrometer's `@Timed` annotation is,
why it works with Spring AOP, but not when using Micrometer as an aspect library for native AspectJ in the context of compile-time weaving (CTW),
e.g. with AspectJ Maven Plugin. It can be made to work with load-time weaving (LTW) when providing an `aop.xml` pointing to `TimedAspect`,
but in a CTW the aspect never kicks in.

The reason is that the aspect has been compiled with Javac, not with the AspectJ compiler (AJC), which is necessary to "finish" the Java class,
i.e. to enhance its byte code in order to be a full AspectJ aspect. The LTW agent does that on the fly during class-loading, but in a CTW context
you need to explicitly tell AJC to do post-compile weaving (a.k.a. binary weaving) on the Micrometer library, producing newly woven class files.
This is done by putting Micrometer on AJC's ***inpath*** in order to make sure that its class files are being transformed and written to the target
directory. The inpath in AspectJ Maven is configured via `<weaveDependencies>`. There are at least two ways to do this:

- You can either create your own woven version of the library in a separate Maven module and then use that module instead of Micrometer.
  In that case, you need to exclude the original Micrometer library in the consuming module, in order to make sure that the unwoven
  class files are not on the classpath anymore and accidentally used.
- The way shown here in this example project is a single-module approach, building an executable uber JAR with Maven Shade. The Micrometer class
  files are not a re-usable library like in the first approach, but it is nice for demonstration purposes, because we can just run the sample
  application and check its output:

```
$ mvn clean package

...
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.12.6:compile (default) @ SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726 ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())' in Type 'de.scrum_master.app.Application' (Application.java:23) advised by around advice from 'io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect' (micrometer-core-1.7.0.jar!TimedAspect.class(from TimedAspect.java))
...
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (default) @ SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726 ---
[INFO] Including org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.12 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.7.0 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing C:\Users\me\java-src\SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726\target\SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with C:\Users\me\java-src\SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726\target\SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: C:\Users\me\java-src\SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726\target\dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ java -jar target/SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Juni 05, 2021 1:12:27 PM io.micrometer.core.instrument.push.PushMeterRegistry start
INFO: publishing metrics for LoggingMeterRegistry every 1m
Juni 05, 2021 1:13:00 PM io.micrometer.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry lambda$publish$5
INFO: method.timed{class=de.scrum_master.app.Application,exception=none,method=doSomething} throughput=0.166667/s mean=0.11842469s max=0.2146482s
```

Please specifically note those log lines (line breaks inserted for better readability):

```
Join point 'method-execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())'
  in Type 'de.scrum_master.app.Application' (Application.java:23)
  advised by around advice from 'io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect'
  (micrometer-core-1.7.0.jar!TimedAspect.class(from TimedAspect.java))
```

The above is proof that the `@Timed` annotation actually causes Micrometer's `TimedAspect` to be woven into our application code. And here are
the measurements created by the aspect for the sample application:

```
method.timed
  {class=de.scrum_master.app.Application,exception=none,method=doSomething}
  throughput=0.166667/s mean=0.11842469s max=0.2146482s
```

Comment: is there something similar to `<weaveDependencies>` in gradle? as we need to use gradle not maven in our project build. And do we need a special graldew build command for aspectJ? Here is the repo of my [test project](https://github.com/selimelawwa/micrometer-test) Would appreciate if you can check it.

Comment: I am not a Gradle user, but just like you could, I looked into Freefair's documentation. I guess, you want to use [`io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving`](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/6.0.0-m2/reference/#_io_freefair_aspectj_post_compile_weaving). Alternatively, like Jonatan said, you could simply use LTW (if compile-time weaving is not compulsory), i.e. start your JVM with `java -javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` and a corresponding `aop.xml` file referring to `TimedAspect`. In that case, you could do completely without the AspectJ compiler.

Comment: In my app scope I am not responsible for starting the JVM. I build my project and provide it as a jar for the application using it. So I guess post compile weaving should fix this right? I will look into how to do this using`Gradle` and`freefair`. Do you have other alternative for `post-compile-weaving` or another library to do this?

Comment: Like I said, I do not use Gradle. Very rarely I build some sample project in order to help someone here. On Gradle there seems to be no de facto standard like AspectJ Maven Plugin for Maven projects, but why would you want to juggle many balls instead of focusing on the one you are using now and learn how to properly set it up first? You have to mimic what I do in my own solution or the alternative I was also describing above. There will be no magical solution doing the whole work for you. Just dig in and solve it. If there are problems, ask a new, more specific question.

Comment: I am not not looking for alternative. Your solution works but not for gradle, which was stated in the original question. I am trying to get it work, so I can mark your question as correct and add the gradle part. Thanks

Comment: My solution explains how to do it, independently of the build tool used. You can replicate both variants I explained on the command line, only using `ajc` commands. Insofar, it is correct and since 2.5 years ago Micrometer #1149 was opened, I am the first person to actually answer that question with regard to CTW. Others only talked about LTW or Spring or were suggesting workarounds with a meta aspect triggering the original aspect, like the one you are using.

Comment: My solution also works for Gradle, you just need to figure out how, also doing part of your own job as a developer - unless you are expecting me to not only present a solution but to also port it from Maven to Gradle for you. I suggest you try by yourself first and then ask a new question, pointing to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, asking more concrete questions than "can you do it for me?".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you expect from this:

```java
public Object handle(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    return timedAspect.timedMethod(pjp);
}
```

If I understand this correctly, it does nothing.
There are [guides](https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj) that you can follow to set-up AspectJ properly for your project. After it is done `TimedAspect` should work, you don't need `MeasuredAspect` or `@Measured` just set up AspectJ.

Comment: In my AppMetrics constructor I initialize an instance of micrometer's [TimedAspect](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/aop/TimedAspect.java) `this.timedAspect = new TimedAspect(registry);` which is the micrometer's aspect that intercepts methods with @Timed annotation. So what `handle` is it let the ProceedingJoinPoint go through micrometer `TimedAspect` handling as if the @Timed works.

Comment: I saw that, but again: without setting up AspectJ properly, your code won't do anything. And with the AspectJ setup, you don't need MeasuredAspect or @Measured. :)

Comment: Specifically, here we really need post-compile weaving, because the aspect class file in Micrometer is a simple Java class, i.e. we need to make sure that the AspectJ compiled transforms the aspect into a real AspectJ aspect first. So "just set up AspectJ correctly" is by no way trivial in this case. Therefore, your answer is not really helpful.

Comment: That's somehow missing from the question. I think my answer should answer the question. TimedAspect works well with runtime weaving. I think from this perspective MeasuredAspect is the same.

Comment: Probably you mean load-time weaving when talking about AspectJ, runtime weaving rather reminds me of Spring AOP. I see nothing missing in the question, the OP mentioned a Gradle AspectJ compiler plugin (Freefair). So it is quite obvious that he wants to use CTW.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@kriegaex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082681/kriegaex)'s Maven solution https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_MicrometerTimed_67803726, this is what I came up with for Gradle.

> **IMPORTANT** once you have produced your jar, it *replaces* micrometer-core, so remember to exclude the original micrometer-core
> from your dependencies. If you don't, it will be the luck of the draw
> which TimedAspect and CountedAspect classes are chosen by your
> runtime.

The goal is to produce a replacement jar for io.micrometer:micrometer-core. This involves compiling with ajc the original micrometer-core jar together with its transitive dependencies. The original micrometer-core contains only two `@Aspect`s, TimedAspect and CountedAspect, so only those classes will changed by ajc.

*build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving' version '6.6'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.9.1'
    inpath 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.10.2'
}

jar {
    exclude 'dummy'
}

sourcesJar {
    exclude 'dummy'
}

// Since I'm only compiling micrometer's library code, I don't need linting
compileJava.ajc.options.compilerArgs += "-Xlint:ignore"
```

Gradle won't allow me to compile without at least one java class to compile. To work around this, I created the following class. Yes, this does get compiled, but does not get included in the jar because it is filtered out by the jar's `exclude` path.

*dummy.Dummy.java*

```
package dummy;

public class Dummy {

  public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```